# Absolute values of coordinates (basis representation).

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, schauder-basis

It looks very simple, but I couldn't check this.

Let $(X, \|\cdot\|)$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ (over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), where $\| \cdot \|$ is a norm on $X$.

Let $\{e_1, \cdots, e_n\}$ be an algebraic basis of $X$ with $\|e_i\| =1$ for all $1\leq i \leq n$.

For $x \in X$, write $x = a_1 e_1 + \cdots + a_n e_n$, where $a_1, \cdots a_n$ are scalars.

If $\|x\| \leq 1$, then is it true that $|a_1|, \cdots, |a_n| \leq 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not true. Here's a counterexample in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual Euclidean norm.

The green circle has radius $1$. The basis vectors $e_1$ and $e_2$ are the black ones. The red vector $x$ obviously has $\|x\| <1$. But also $x = \tfrac32e_1 + \tfrac32e_2$, so $a_1=a_2 = \tfrac32$.

[image]